# What happens if I do `mount --bind /dev` to a chroot directory and I remove it inside the chroot directory?

Tags: boot, permissions, mount, chroot

What happens if I do `mount --bind /dev` to a chroot directory and I chroot to the chroot directory and inside remove the /dev/ folder. I thought my host's /dev directory will be deleted but [the web page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization) I was reading says this :

> The above commands will mount important directories of your host
> system to the edit directory. If you later decide to delete the edit
> directory, make sure to unmount all of them before doing so (see the
> Cleanup chapter below). Otherwise, your host system will become
> unusable until you reboot it.

So it's saying if I reboot my host it'll be ok. Is this true?

Comment: You cannot delete a mount point.

Comment: yeah, I tried a simple test, when I removed the files under the mount point, the files are also removed in the host file system. I don't know why the web page said like that.

Comment: @user535733 No, that's enough. I'll put an answer myself.

Answer (score 0):

as muru commented, I can't remove a mount point, only I can remove the files under that mount point. I did a simple test below (as I remember).

```
$sudo debootstrap --arch=amd64 forcal edit
$mkdir mydir; mkdir mydir/{a,b,c}
$mkdir edit/mnt2
$sudo mount --bind mydir edit/mnt2
$sudo chroot edit
(now I'm in the chroot file system)
#ls /mnt2
a b c
#\rm /mnt2/c
#exit
$ls mydir
a b
```

I could see the file I removed in the chroot file system is actally removed in the host file system as I expected.

Answer (score 0):

*"What happens if I do mount --bind /dev to a chroot directory and I chroot to the chroot directory and inside remove the /dev/ folder...* **So it's saying if I reboot my host it'll be ok.**

- No, that's not exactly what it is saying, but yes, it's true for what is being described on the web page which is different than what you're explaining.

### To elaborate:

The statement quoted isn't inferring, specifically, that there will be a *restoration of deleted or removed files that occurs from within a bind mount filesystem of a chroot environment* of some sort, but rather, only states that system *usability* won't be restored until after a reboot under the event that one should decide to delete the `/edit` directory without first unmounting the various sub paths that would've also been bound to the sub paths in the `/edit` directory of the primary system. To be sure, the `/edit` directory is the same one which one is instructed to `chroot` into for the LiveCD customization process being described.

With that said, just as you expected and as you've already shown in your own answer, removing files from a directory that is bind mounted while you are in chroot will also remove those files from the directory it is bound to (in this scenario, the primary system). But, what is being described on the page happens upon exiting chroot and removing the `/edit` directory while it is still mounted with its bound mounts would, at least back then, also remove them *in a sense* from the primary system. See more from the [bugs](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html#BUGS) section of the `mount` man page.

### What Reboot Makes Right Again

The idea that the system will become usable after reboot comes from the fact that the mount sub paths mentioned, as further explained below, involves specifically *those* mount points:

```
sudo mount --bind /dev/ edit/dev
sudo chroot edit
mount -t proc none /proc
mount -t sysfs none /sys
mount -t devpts none /dev/pts
```

Since above are all mount points that refer to pseudo filesystems and in a way can be thought of as being regenerated each time the kernel boots and hardware is detected. Then, it may be more understandable how the statement itself is true but the hypothetical scenario you explained was different and before confirming that it is true, required making clear the understanding and distinctions that:

- You're describing removal of items in a chroot environment within that filesystem where you are acting as root and while it's being used by the primary system simultaneously (in which case you'll run into permission issues anyway) but in that regard, you are telling the system in the chroot environment to remove those items, essentially notifying the system of their removal. As opposed to...
- The article describes a scenario where all the system references is abruptly deleted and removed upon deletion of the working directory, where there is a sharing of mounts across namespaces while namespaces are associated with processes and exiting the chroot releases the primary system's direct access to them, leaving them open and possibly other running daemons within that namespace created, and then removing that namespace from the seat of the primary system disrupts all the endpoints, synchronous data ,and kernel/kernel settings references that existed before it's sudden removal. In other words, from a system standpoint, it doesn't know where those directories suddenly went when you delete the directory containing their mount points. Refer to the kernel documentation for [filesystems and shared subtrees](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sharedsubtree.txt).
- Only the `/dev` directory is mounted with bind from the primary system, while `sys`, `proc`, and `/dev/pts` are mounted from within chroot, which creates a private instance of the various filesystems such that [objects created in this new instance are independent of the other instances](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html#FILESYSTEM-SPECIFIC_MOUNT_OPTIONS) of those same directories (i.e. the primary system's instance of each directory)
- `/sys` is not a real on-disk filesystem: it's a representation of and a means to access state in the form of a virtual filesystem. It is entirely RAM-based and contents of `/sys` are not stored on disk as explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/538931/414107).
- `/dev` is a special directory for device files and is a `tmpfs` variant (devtmpfs). These are abstractions, they are not real files on disk. The directory is populated at boot and subject to change to reflect existing device interfaces, which are created and destroyed by the kernel and a userspace daemon, `udevd`. (As explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/93535/414107).)
- `/dev/pts` are representations of virtual systems specific to being console devices. Each entry found in here is created when you open a local GUI terminal. (as explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/79351/414107).)
- `/proc` or *procfs* is also a fully virtual filesystem with the kernel controlling all operations and defines their structure (As explained [here](https://superuser.com/a/1362914/1168619).)

Thus, upon reboot, these filesystems are regenerated by the kernel and would replace those virtually existing filesystems, bringing functionality back to the system if halted by the deletion of the `/edit` containing those still mounted directories *after exiting* chroot.

### To summarize:

In case it's caused more confusion than clarity, yes, technically it's true that if you were able to successfully remove the `/dev` folder somehow within chroot, after a reboot your primary system would be restored. But, again, what you described involved chroot'ing into the filesystem and removing something as chroot while the guide points out how leaving chroot and then deleting the working directory from outside chroot would cause issues. So, while your understanding in the general sense would've been correct, the two situations when compared are completely different and the understanding of what would be restored upon reboot should help clarify why I initially said no, that's not what it's saying but now describe it as yes, being true.

***Added side notes***:

- This portion of the guide is a bit outdated and was added back in 2008 with [revision 78](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization?action=recall&rev=78) and with older kernels (somewhere around 3.x) bind mounts were truly indistinguishable from the original. It wasn't until around 2012 that kernels began tracking bind mounts and exposing the information through `/proc/PID/mountinfo` which meant that if you had removed `/edit` while it still had mounted `/edit/proc`n `/edit/sys`, and `/edit/dev/pts` in its directory/filesystem, which were bound to the primary system's `/proc/` `/sys`, and `/dev/pts` respectively, then their removal also applies to the primary system, just as you've confirmed in your above answer.
- On modern systems, we would more likely run into file permission issues and restrictions to prevent the system halt from occurring in the first place, when attempting to delete the `/edit` directory without unmounting.
- There is a great write-up on bind mounts that provides a more user-friendly and easily understandable explanation of bind mounts [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/198591/414107).

*In conclusion, perhaps it was all just a matter of semantics, but it seemed like there perhaps there was still somewhat of a disconnect as to why that was stated while your tests proved what you understood to be true. And, hopefully is now more apparent, that they were of slightly different interpretations of very similar things.*